# Additional values in CHtml::checkBoxList

Tags: yii

Is there a solution for additional values in CHtml::checkBoxList?

Now i do this:

```
    <?php
        echo CHtml::checkBoxList(
            'tinyList', 
            '', 
            array("value1" => "label1", "value2" => "label2", "value3" => "label3"),
            array(
                'template'  => '<tr><td><img src="{imagePath}" /></td><td>{label}</td><td>{quantity}</td><td>{input}</td></tr>',
                'container' => 'tbody'
                ));
    ?>
```

and i get this result:

```
     <tbody id="tinyList">
         <tr>
             <td><img src="{imagePath}" /></td>
             <td><label for="tinyList_0">label1</label></td>
             <td>{quantity}</td>
             <td><input value="value1" id="tinyList_0" type="checkbox" name="tinyList[]" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><img src="{imagePath}" /></td>
             <td><label for="tinyList_1">label2</label></td>
             <td>{quantity}</td>
             <td><input value="value2" id="tinyList_1" type="checkbox" name="tinyList[]" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><img src="{imagePath}" /></td>
             <td><label for="tinyList_2">label3</label></td>
             <td>{quantity}</td>
             <td><input value="value3" id="tinyList_2" type="checkbox" name="tinyList[]" /></td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
```

(how) can i fill the missing parts "imagePath" and "quantity"?

Comment: Chechboxlist should be just that, a list of checkboxes. Write your table separately.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two placeholders can be passed into `CHtml::checkBoxList` - `{label}` and `{input}`.

`CHtml::checkBoxList` knows nothing about `imagePath` or `quantity`. 
Hence it can't add them into template.

The only solution I can see is using `CListView` widget with custom view file, which would represent tempate you need.

Also you need to define data structure wich would have all required values.
Let it be like this:

```
$rawData=array(
    array(
        'inputValue'=>'value 1',
        'inputLabel'=>'label 1',
        'quantity'=>23,
        'imagePath'=>'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png'
    ),
    array(
        'inputValue'=>'value 2',
        'inputLabel'=>'label 2',
        'quantity'=>21,
        'imagePath'=>'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png'
    ),
    array(
        'inputValue'=>'value 3',
        'inputLabel'=>'label 3',
        'quantity'=>56,
        'imagePath'=>'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png'
    )
);
```

Then main view file would look like this:

```
<table>
<?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array('keyField'=>false)),
        'itemView'=>'_item',
        'template'=>'{items}'
    ));
?>
</table>
```

and `_item`:

```
<?php
    $id='option-'.$index;
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo CHtml::image($data['imagePath']) ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo CHtml::label($data['inputLabel'], $id)?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $data['quantity'] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo CHtml::checkBox('tinyList', false, array('value'=>$data['inputValue'], 'id'=>$id)) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

above code gives me a table with image, label, number and checkbox in each row.

Also `CGridView` might be helpfull....

I hope this helps.